# how do I use two parent forks and one child in a child_process?

Tags: node.js, fork, child-process

I'm trying to send data from a different process to another process using `child_process.fork()`. I feel like I'm almost there.

The data is coming from `for loop`, which then sends `POST` request and initializes a child_process ffmpeg request, after that uses a promise to wait for `data` from `stdout`, once that happens, I'm calling a new function that forks a new child_process that sends an object.

I'm sending a stringified object (or just a string to test) to socket-handler.js (unrelated name)
// first parent, data is sent from here.
const child = fork("./src/lib/socket-handler.js", [JSON.stringify(stream)]); // It seems like I can't use process.send() in a process.on('message') event so I'm trying to use args.
child.send({ message: "from stream-handler" }); // Just a test string

I'm unable to use process.send('message') in process.on('message') for some reason, it does NOT send anything to the other parent.

```
 // child, socket-handler.js

process.on("message", function (obj) {
  // process.send(obj) // Doesn't emit anything.
});
process.send(process.argv[2]); // emits once, which is "undefined".
```

The first message from `process.argv[2]` is actually `undefined`, then `dev`, then the actual `obj` I'm sending (as a string). But because the outside process.send only sends it once, all I get from the second parent is `undefined`.

```
// second parent

  const child = fork("./src/lib/socket-handler.js", [], {
    silent: true,
  });
  child.on("message", function (message) {
    console.log("parent recieved message:", message);
  });
```

Here's my attempt to fetch that data. I'm not getting anything. I don't even know I'm even getting that `undefined` here as it's all confusing.

How do I do this correctly so I can get that data from the child?